# How to link taxonomy term with its content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks, 7

This is the code below that i am used

```
$ch=db_query("SELECT th.tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy th 
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data td ON th.tid=td.tid
  INNER JOIN field_data_field_books book ON book.field_books_tid = th.tid
  WHERE td.vid = '6' AND th.parent = $tid AND book.entity_id = $nid")->FetchField();

"<h1>Pages</h1>";

$chap = taxonomy_get_children($ch);
foreach($chap as $ca){
  print "<br>Chapter===>".$ca->name;
}
```

how I link taxonomy terms using the above code?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can use [**l()**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)

```
  $ch = db_query("SELECT th.tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy th 
        INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data td ON th.tid=td.tid 
        INNER JOIN field_data_field_books book ON book.field_books_tid = th.tid
        WHERE td.vid = '6' AND th.parent = $tid AND book.entity_id = $nid")->FetchField();

  $chap = taxonomy_get_children($ch);
  foreach ($chap as $ca) {
    print l($ca->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $ca->tid);
  }
```

Comment: when i am using this code no data displayed

Comment: Can you check your query? Whats is the value of `$ch`?

Comment: volume 1,volume 2 volume 3

Comment: What are volume 1,volume 2 and volume 3? Are they **taxonomy names**? But according to the **QUERY**, you suppose to get **TERM ID**?

Comment: yes its taxonomy terms name i am using term id to get children of parent id

Comment: But according to the **QUERY**, you suppose to get **TERM ID**. How you are getting the **taxonomy names**? Are they **Parent Taxonomy  names**? `th.tid` should return the parent **tid**.

Comment: $nid=arg(1); used to take current tid of the page and book.entity_id='$nid'load tid of the page its works dynamically